# Dual boot Ubuntu after format, it seems I have both Ubuntu versions now

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

Title can be confusing, I wanted to summarize my problem. I am open to suggestions, so sorry for that.

I had Windows 11 and Ubuntu 18.04 both installed as dual boot. I wanted to delete Ubuntu 18.04 completely and boot Ubuntu 20.04 instead. I have 500 GB disk, I reserved 50 GB of space for Ubuntu 18.04 when I installed it and free space was 12 GB. This morning I plugged my 20.04 ISO and I manually selected that Ubuntu 18.04 allocated partition and checked "Format this partition" box. After format, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 to this partition.

I realized that, 38 GB part of the disk is still held by Ubuntu 18.04 I guess and is not empty. I only downloaded CUDA 11.2/CuDNN 8.2 and I have insufficient disk space.

Here is my disk allocation graph:

[image: Here is my disk allocation graph]

What to do now, should I completely remove this 50 GB partition and boot again?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your analysis of the situation is incorrect. Your screenshot indicates the partition is 50 GB while you are using nearly 20 GB for your home directory and 18 GB for two directories within your usr directory. Your issue is cause by not having a large enough partition for the operating system. Ubuntu 18.04 clearly was replaced with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It would be 1,000,000 % better for you to use virtual machines to experiment instead of the rigidity of old fashioned dual boot.

Comment: @John, as a dual-boot user, I enjoy the advantages of 1. Operating with only a *single* OS required, not being dependent on another. 2. Being able to boot an alternate OS if there is an issue with the other. 3. On older PC's, unable to run Windows 11 without unauthorized work-around, when Windows 10 is no longer updated, they'll easily be switched to Ubuntu *only*.

Comment: I see your point but if my host machine failed as often as dual boot systems fail in here, nothing would ever get done. I dumped dual boot a quarter of a century ago and never once looked back